# navigator.camera.getPicture dont opens the device's default camera application

Tags: android, cordova

I have a android application but I cant use camera.
The app always open the gallery.
I try set sourceType like Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA but dont work... always open gallery... what is wrong?

Code:

```
(function () {

document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );
function onDeviceReady() {

    var buttonTakePhoto = document.querySelector("#btnTakePhoto");
    if (buttonTakePhoto != null) {
        buttonTakePhoto.addEventListener("click", capturePhoto, false);
    }

};

function capturePhoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA });
};

//Callback function when the picture has been successfully taken
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
    // Unhide image elements
    smallImage.style.display = 'block';
    smallImage.src = imageData;
};

//Callback function when the picture has not been successfully taken
function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed to load picture because: ' + message);
};
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>   
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

</head>
<body>

    <input type="button" value="Tirar Foto" id="btnTakePhoto" class="quitButton" />

    <img id="smallImage"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/takePhoto.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Work!

Add **mediaType:Camera.MediaType.CAMERA** in options.

```
function capturePhoto() {
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, mediaType: Camera.MediaType.CAMERA });
```